# Good way to enter input to a 2d integer array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

So I want to create a 2D array in C++ and enter input to it.

```
int** arr = new int*[arrrows];
```

I have written a function that allows me to enter input to a 1D array.

```
void fillintarray(int* arr, int arrsize)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < arrrows; i++)
    {
        std::cin >> arr[i];
    }
}
```

Now I tried to create a function to enter input to a 2D array using the 1D function

```
void fill2dintarray(int** arr, int arrrows, int arrcols)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < arrrows; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = new int[arrcols];
        fillintarray(arr[i], arrcols);
    }
}
```

So would this implementation work correctly? Also, it would be helpful if you could tell me some more good ways to enter input into a 2D array; I'm new to C++. Thanks!

Comment: I'd start by use a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` if the column width is unknown at compile time, otherwise `std::vector<std::array<int, N>>` instead, rather than manually managing dynamic memory.Extremely rare is the case for using manual memory management in modern C++, so just don't. Regardless, you asked *"So would this implementation work correctly?"* - so... what happened when you *tried it* ?

Comment: `int** arr = new int*[arrrows];` nope nope nope. all sorts of nopes. Use standard containers. Don't use manual memory management. It's C++ and it's 2019. Stop writing this kind of code.

Comment: @WhozCraig I haven't learned about vectors yet, so I am trying to work with what I can.

Comment: Looks correct. It would be better to use STL if you are working with C++ (std::vector or std::array, or std::valarray), then the code would be simpler (they wrap the size, do not decay into pointers, check the ranges, possible to use as return type, allows generic code etc). You could also define operator>> on your container.

Comment: @IUissopretty that is a bad approach. Don't learn bad behaviors because you didn't learn vectors. Use a book that teaches modern C++. Doing it the way you are doing it is a bad practice, ugly code, and very very bug prone.

Comment: or, alternatively write C. But if you write C++, don't write this kind of code. Ever!

Comment: @bolov Ya, I understand. Just started learning C++, so just trying to get the basics down as of now. I will learn about the standard libraries later.

Comment: @IUissopretty no. Writing manual memory management is NOT the basics of C++. That's what I am trying to say. You need to start with standard containers. You should never have to write manual memory management in C++! It's archaic and a leftover from C. And it's complicated and difficult to understand and very error prone. Don't learn that! C++ offers abstractions that are easier to understand and most importantly safer. Anyway, that's my advice. Take it or leave it.

Comment: @IUissopretty learning how to manage memory manually is a great exercise. There is a LOT of code written from the late '80s up until the container libraries were implemented that contains `new` and `delete`. While the container libraries hide the memory management from the programmer, there is no excuse not to know how to deal with it correctly. In your case you want to allocate pointers for rows and arrays of integers to assign to each of the pointers. By using `int**` you can reallocate both the number of rows and columns as needed. However YOU must handle tracking the cols filled per row

Comment: @bolov Understood. Thanks, I'll take the advice.

Comment: The worst thing that can happen is you sit down for your big $$ interview and the boss at MegaCorp. hands you a quick problem that says, "You have `int** arr = new int*[arrrows];` and the number of rows exceeds `arrrows`, How do you handle it?" You might find it very important to know how to use `new` and `delete` in that case. Both `new` and `delete` are just as much part of C++ as `vector` and `tuple` are. @bolov is correct and new code should be written going forward, but a significant minority, if not majority, of existing C++ still contains `new` and `delete`.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I would recommend you use `vector` instead of handling raw pointers yourself. A 2D array with 5 rows can be represented as `std::vector<std::vector<int> > arr(5)`. Then you just need to populate each row by pushing the input into it.

e.g.

```cpp
void fill2dintarray(std::vector<std::vector<int> > &arr, int arrrows, int arrcols)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < arrrows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < arrcols; j++)
        {
            int temp;
            std::cin >> temp;
            arr[i].push_back(temp);
        }
    }
}

int arrrows = 5;
int arrcols = 5;
std::vector<std::vector<int> > arr(arrrows);
fill2dintarray(arr, arrrows, arrcols);
```

Or, if your input is already in the form of 2D array such as

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

you can consider reading a whole line as string, turn the string into stringstream, and use empty space as delimiter to feed each value to each row of your 2D array. You can see this [Quora answer](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-split-a-string-by-space-into-an-array-in-c++) for inspiration.